# Regex to match everything between multiple set of brackets

Tags: regex, brackets, alteryx

I am trying to match everything between multiple set of brackets

Example of data

```
[[42.30722,-83.181125],[42.30722,-83.18112667],[42.30722167,-83.18112667,[42.30721667,-83.181125],[+42.30721667,-83.181125]]
```

I need to match everything within the inner brackets as below

```
42.30722,-83.181125,
42.30722,-83.18112667,
42.30722167,-83.18112667,
42.30721667,-83.181125,
+42.30721667,-83.181125
```

How do I do that. I tried `\[([^\[\]]|)*\]` but it gives me values with brackets. Can anybody please help me with this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Doesn't seem like this is the kind of thing regex is suited for. Are you able to parse it as an array?

Comment: What code are you using?

Comment: I tried [^\[\]]+(?=]) in Alteryx. It seems to get the output what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like one of them is missing a bracket maybe, or if not, maybe some expression similar to:

```
\[([+-]?\d+\.\d+)\s*,\s*([+-]?\d+\.\d+)\s*\]?
```

might be OK to start with.

#### Test

```
import re

expression = r"\[([+-]?\d+\.\d+)\s*,\s*([+-]?\d+\.\d+)\s*\]?"
string = """
[[42.30722,-83.181125],[42.30722,-83.18112667],[42.30722167,-83.18112667,[42.30721667,-83.181125],[+42.30721667,-83.181125]]
"""

print([list(i) for i in re.findall(expression, string)])
print(re.findall(expression, string))
```

#### Output

```
[['42.30722', '-83.181125'], ['42.30722', '-83.18112667'], ['42.30722167', '-83.18112667'], ['42.30721667', '-83.181125'], ['+42.30721667', '-83.181125']]
[('42.30722', '-83.181125'), ('42.30722', '-83.18112667'), ('42.30722167', '-83.18112667'), ('42.30721667', '-83.181125'), ('+42.30721667', '-83.181125')]
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/CivIiC/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/CivIiC/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but figured I would include it anyhow.

Your 3rd set is missing a ']'.

If that is in there, then in Alteryx, you can just use Text to Columns splitting to Rows and ignore delimiter in brackets